# ColdFusion ORM Caching and LogSQL

Tags: hibernate, caching, orm, coldfusion, application.cfc

Ive been playing with ORM caching in the past few days and one thing that is confusing me a lot is the  SQL is still logged (when I have logSQL = true) to the console even with caching enabled. This makes me think that caching is not working, I would think that hibernate doesnt create the sql since it sees the object in cache, but maybe hibernate generates the sql even before checking ehcache.

My code is below just incase someone picks up something I missed.
Application.cfc

```
this.ormSettings.secondarycacheenabled = "true";
this.ormSettings.cacheprovider="ehcache";
this.ormSettings.logSQL=true;
```

then my Books cfc

```
component persistent="true" entityname="Books" table="db_books"  cacheuse="transactional"  lazy="true"
```

and lastly the code im using to call.

```
    a = entityloadbypk("Books","1");
writeoutput(a.getName());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've read and experienced first hand, the SQL transferred over the wire to your DBMS will always be logged regardless of whether ColdFusion ORM (Hibernate) is generating it JIT, or pulling it from cache. If anything, you could run a few benchmarks to quickly identify whether cache actually being used, or not.